# finished with non-zero exit value error

Tags: android, android-studio

I've tried any solution suggested trying to solved the aapt.exe error.
every time I'm trying to add a new dependency to the build.gradle I get this error and after removing the dependency the error disappear. 
I've tried chnging the compile SDK, changing the build tools version, invalidate/clear cache, activating compile independent modules in parallel.
The only dependencies registered are:

```
 signingConfigs {    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
        compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
        compile files('libs/android-integration-3.2.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/android-core-3.2.1.jar')
```

How can I handle it if I need to add another dependency to my project?

I'm working on android studio 1.4.1
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

Comment: Did you add: `multiDexEnabled true` inside defaultConfig Gradle file?

Comment: Why are your dependencies inside `signingConfigs` ?

Answer (score 0):

you should be adding your dependency libraries in `build.gradle` in (Module:app), if you are adding any library using Android studio GUI it will end up adding that library in this place or if you manually place a library in `libs` and add it to project as library it will still be added here.

Kindly check where and how are you adding your dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
}
```

in above code gson library is added `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'` is added using android studio GUI and

apache common io is added `compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')`
 by placing it's library in `libs` directory in the Android project

Comment: Did it but still.. I can't add any library through android studio GUI. my current build.gradle dependencies are:     dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
        compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
        compile files('libs/android-core-3.2.1.jar')
        compile files('libs/android-integration-3.2.1.jar')
    }

Comment: what error are you getting here ?, if possible post your build.gradle in your question

Comment: Well actually the dependencies only work if I add them by placing the lib (.jar file) in the android project directory

Comment: I think so. Never had other problems. Also my Android studio is updated and so are my SDK in my SDK manager

Comment: If I'm adding the line :compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1', for example, i get the following error: Error:Execution failed for task ':MYTGuideApp:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Erez\AppData\Local\Android\sdk2\build-tools\21.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: do you have two different sdk's on your computer ?

Comment: the first one was deleted but the second remain as sdk2 because all the projects related